# Подсчет значений в новом столбце сводной таблицы pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Есть сводная таблица в пандасе с кодом

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
...                          "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
...                    "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
...                          "one", "one", "two", "two"],
...                    "C": ["2017", "2017", "2018", "2017",
...                          "2018", "2017", "2018", "2017",
...                          "2017"],
...                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
dataf = df.pivot_table(values="D", index=["A","B"], columns=["C"], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True, dropna=True)
dataf
C       2017    2018    All
A   B           
bar one 4.0     5.0     9
two     13.0    NaN    13
foo one 3.0     2.0     5
two     3.0     3.0     6
All     23.0    10.0   33
```

Я хочу добавить еще столбец который бы считал отношение 2018 к 2017. Как это сделать?
Просто добавить столбец в фрейм я могу, но как обратится к данным 2018, ведь фактически это значения столбца, а не название столбца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [71]: dataf['new'] = dataf['2018'] / dataf['2017']

In [72]: dataf
Out[72]:
C        2017  2018  All       new
A   B
bar one   4.0   5.0    9  1.250000
    two  13.0   NaN   13       NaN
foo one   3.0   2.0    5  0.666667
    two   3.0   3.0    6  1.000000
All      23.0  10.0   33  0.434783
```

PS это решение будет работать если `2017` и `2018` строки:

```
In [75]: dataf.columns.tolist()
Out[75]: ['2017', '2018', 'All']
```

если это числа, то вы получите ошибку:

```
In [76]: dataf.columns = [2017, 2018, 'All']

In [77]: dataf['new'] = dataf['2018'] / dataf['2017']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
skipped
...
KeyError: '2018'
```

в этом случае к именам столбцов нужно обращаться как к числам:

```
In [78]: dataf['new'] = dataf[2018] / dataf[2017]    

In [80]: dataf
Out[80]:
         2017  2018  All       new
A   B
bar one   4.0   5.0    9  1.250000
    two  13.0   NaN   13       NaN
foo one   3.0   2.0    5  0.666667
    two   3.0   3.0    6  1.000000
All      23.0  10.0   33  0.434783
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.